# How to separate controllers by areas in Swagger 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

I'm implementing Swagger in an integrations api and in that case it was necessary to separate these services by area for project organization issues, but I have the following problem, some controllers have common names in different areas and when swagger generates the documentation, even separated by area, if it has the same controller name together, I would like to know if there is any way to separate the controllers by area as well? Below are two integrations: Mercado Livre and Skyhub, both are in different areas, but if they notice the categories they joined because they have the same controller name.

! https://tribofoxcombr-my.sharepoint.com/personal/leonardo_silva_tribofox_com_br/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx?id=%2Fpersonal%2Fleonardo_silva_tribofox_com_br%2FDocuments%2FCompartilhado%2FCapturar%2EPNG&parent=%2Fpersonal%2Fleonardo_silva_tribofox_com_br%2FDocuments%2FCompartilhado&slrid=3e37b79e-f020-7000-b380-a8a0e7785d97

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
    [ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "Group")] 
    public class SomethingController : Controller
    {
```

And in declaration

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerDoc(version,
        new Info
        {
            Title = name,
            Version = version
        }
    );

    options.DocInclusionPredicate((_, api) => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(api.GroupName));

    options.TagActionsBy(api => api.GroupName);
});
```

Comment: Okay, I saw that you could split it in the respective areas, but the question would be to divide into areas and then controllers, would that be possible, or would swagger not support?

Comment: Now if you have how to divide the documentation of swagger into "presentation pages" and each stay with a different area would be better, but all the places that I looked for did not see anyone working with areas.

Comment: `options.TagActionsBy(api => api.GroupName);` is obsolete now and no longer required.